# Align right and left and vertically bottom in the same table cell

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I need to align two texts one is to left and other is to right with in the same table cell.
I could achieve this by doing the followng.

```
    <td valign="bottom" style="vertical-align:bottom;">
     <div style="float:left;text-align:left;">Yes,He is.</div>
     <div style="float:right;text-align:right;"><img src="x.gif" alt="img" height="30px"/>  </div> 
</td>
```

But the thing is the left-aligned text is gone up when I did this. That text should be aligned  to bottom vertically in the table cell. I tried by setting `"vertical-align:bottom"` to td cell. But didnt work.

Can somebody help...here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sKA8a/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap child divs with a outer div and give `position:relative` to outer div and `absolute` to child divs.

**HTML**

```
<td >
    <div class="wrap">
 <div class="left">Yes,He is.</div>
 <div class="right"><img src="x.gif" alt="img" height="30px"/></div>
  </div>
</td>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrap{position:relative;overflow:auto}
.left{text-align:left; bottom:0; position:absolute; left:0}
.right{float:right;text-align:right;}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/sKA8a/3/)

Answer (score 1):

You can work around it, just create a table in the cell with invisible border for all the texts. I do it like that, when im having trouble with things like that.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening cause the image height is 30px and the text height is small.
For aligning to bottom, assign a relative position to the parent td and then assign the text div to the bottom left of the td.

```
<td valign="bottom" style="position:relative;">
 <div style="position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0;;">Yes,He is.</div>
 <div style="float:right;text-align:right;"><img src="x.gif" alt="img" height="30px"/></div>
</td>
```

[JSFIDDLE Link](http://jsfiddle.net/sKA8a/4/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<td valign="bottom" style="vertical-align:bottom;">
  <div style="float:left;text-align:left;line-height:30px;">Yes,He is.</div>
  <div style="float:right;text-align:right;"><img src="x.gif" alt="img" height="30px"/></div>
</td>
```